# Eigenspectra of graphs produced by joining a single edge

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Lets say I have two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ which are defined on a disjoint set of vertices, $V(G_1)$ and $V(G_2)$, such that there is no edge connecting any $V(G_1)$ and $V(G_2)$. So basically I have two disconnected graphs.

Is there any way of relating the eigenvectors &/or eigenvalues of $G_1$ and $G_2$ to the graph obtained by adding one edge that connects $V(G_1)$ and $V(G_2)$ or in the converse direction?

Are there any general or special case (e.g. for regular graphs) results on this?

Comment: So now that the graph is connected, the dimension of the kernel of the Laplacian is smaller, but now instead it has a small eigenvalue which is more or less given by two distinct constants on each of the two components, assuming high enough connectivity in the original graphs. You can try to quantify how small.

Comment: could you elaborate on this? I don't know what the kernel of the laplacian is?

Comment: Do you know what the kernel, also known as the null space, of a matrix/linear transformation is? The graph Laplacian is $D-A$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the degrees on the diagonal and $A$ is the adjacency matrix.

Comment: yes. I know what the laplacian is and didn't realise that the kernel of a matrix was the same as its nullspace but thats clear now, thanks! I apologise but I still don't understand your comment.